# Subscript requires size of interface NSMutableArray which is not cnstant in non-fragile ABI

Tags: objective-c, ios

Below is a snippet where I am getting the error:

```
    -(IBAction)rateButtonClick:(id)sender{

    NSMutableArray *starImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:starImage1, starImage2, starImage3, starImage4, starImage5, nil];

    NSArray *halfRateButton = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:halfRateButton1, halfRateButton2, halfRateButton3, halfRateButton4, halfRateButton5, nil];

    int buttonClicked = (((UIButton *)sender).tag);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < buttonClicked; i++) {
        **starImage[buttonClicked].image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rate.png"];** 
    }

    if (lastButtonClicked != buttonClicked) {
        **starImage[buttonClicked].image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star-half-full.png"];**
    }else
        **starImage[buttonClicked].image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rate.png"];**
        lastButtonClicked = buttonClicked;

    for (i = 0; i <= buttonClicked; i++) {
        **halfRateButton[i].hidden = YES;**
    }
}
```

The error comes in the marked lines. Changing them as

```
    **[starImage objectAtIndex:i].image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rate.png"];**
```

doesn't work out. I get an error:

> image property not found on object of type (id).

Here, satrImage1 to starImage5 are `UIImageViews`. halfRateButton1 to halfRateButton5 are buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know exactly what u want, but I think below answer can help you to get rid of error.
Try this

```
[[starImage objectAtIndex:i] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rate.png"]];
```

or

```
UIImageView *temp = [starImage objectAtIndex:i];
tmp.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rate.png"];
```

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer & pleased to hear that it worked for you :)